# Нужна ли запятая после роль руководителя?

Tags: пунктуация

...подтверждает один непреложный факт – роль руководителя, является главным фактором достижения целей организованных структур.

Когда хочется интонацией сделать паузу, можно ли ставить запятую или нужно опираться только на правила пунктуации?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для запятой между подлежащим и сказуемым нет оснований. Если очень нужно обозначить паузу (напр. для последующего декламирования текста), то без каких-либо нарушений можно поставить многоточие.

Answer (score 0):

Из Вашей пунктуации следует, что что-то подтверждает и является. Если это так, то запятая на месте.

Но если ***роль является***, то запятой (между подлежащим и сказуемом) однозначно быть не должно. А после слова *факт* лучше поставить двоеточие.

Comment: получилось так Изучение тысячелетней истории организаций и развития феномена управления, будь то управление племенной общиной или международной корпорацией, подтверждает один непреложный факт: роль руководителя является главным фактором достижения целей организованных структур